# React and SVG. Works for JSX, fails when used in Style

Tags: reactjs, svg, jsx

Here's my component. When I use the SVG from within JSX, it renders OK:

```
   import React from "react";
    import Radium from 'radium';
    import LogoSvg from '../../images/my_logo.svg';


    class HeaderBar extends React.Component {

        render () {

            return (
                <div>
                    <LogoSvg />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

export default Radium(HeaderBar);
```

however, when I change to this, nothing is rendered. It's as if the `backgroundImage` isn't even taken in. Changing the `backgroundImage` to a simple `background: 'red'` works well. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import React from "react";
import Radium from 'radium';
import LogoSvg from '../../images/my_logo.svg';

class HeaderBar extends React.Component {

    render () {
        const style = {
            backgroundImage: `url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${LogoSvg})`,
            width: '500px',
            height: '500px'
        };

        return (
            <div style={style}>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Radium(HeaderBar);
```

I use webpack 4 with:

```
 test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "react-svg-loader",
            options: {
              jsx: true // true outputs JSX tags
            }
          }
        ]
```

Comment: Post code for LogoSvg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because `react-svg-loader` will return a React component which renders an inline svg. You simply want the inline svg if you're using a data image. Maybe try svg-inline-loader instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can't find the path to your svg image because of the `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,` in front of it. It will work if you change it to:

```
const style = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${LogoSvg})`,
        width: '500px',
        height: '500px'
};
```

or inline:

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${LogoSvg})`}>
```

Comment: No effect. Sorry.

Comment: Hmm what does your LogoSvg look like? I've tried on my localhost with svg before leaving the answer, so not sure why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: It's my company name, in "large friendly letters". The SVG is healthy, in fact, it renders fine when I use it inside `JSX`. My purpose is to use it within CSS as `backgroundImage`